# Bluetooth app need to check for other users with the same app

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I need a suggestion to implement a bluetooth application:
it scan for devices and have to check if the discovered devices has the same application installed.
There's a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

"a Bluetooth device within the local area will respond to a discovery request only if it is currently enabled to be discoverable. If a device is discoverable, it will respond to the discovery request by sharing some information, such as the **device name,** **class,** and its **unique MAC address.** Using this information, the device performing discovery can then choose to initiate a connection to the discovered device.

So i guess the device need to accept the connection to get more information about installed apps and other.

Comment: Yes, i know that but the searching and the adding of the devices is done in the application, if it scan every avaiable MACs I want to check if i can add in a listview wich will make an index of all avaiable device that have the my app.

Comment: a solution would be to log all devices Mac in a database on the internet. Then if a device scan and find a device it can check if that device is registered on the database and active or something :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it give me an idea.

Comment: @Lucarnosky did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @KishanSolanki Well, after so many years I even forgot about this question. In any case yes, the solution is what was suggested, save the list in a DB and check if the MAC address you just detected is contained in the list of the MACs on your DB.